# Do I need to define models for all associations?

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

If I have a users table and an email table, do I have to define an `email.php` model to define this relation in `User.php`:

```
static $has_many = array(
      array('emails')
    );
```

Also, if I have an object like email that can be has foreign key relationships with other objects that can own that object, how do I define that an email can `belong_to users` AND `belong_to domains`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to define a model if it uses phpAR default naming conventions.
   Although you probably want to, if you use associations. If you don't define the `Email` model and its `belongs_to` relationship to `User`, you won't be able to access `User` through `Email` (only viceversa, `Email` through `User`)
2. Multiple `belongs_to` are achieved through arrays:

   ```
   class Email extends ActiveRecord\Model {
       static $belongs_to = array(
           array('user'),
           array('domain')
       );
   }
   ```

Note that for `belongs_to` you have to use the singular form, not the plural

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a framework?

If not you should use a static getter for each Model.

You should use lazyloading on it's data fields.

So if you write email->getUser() you will get a user object which only knows it's id and can lazy load data when needed from the db.

Be aware always to know what you are doing (sometimes it's better to use a join to avoid N Queries (when working with loops or fetching data threw more than 2 tables)).

I recommend you not to write your own ORM or Active Records implementation unless you would like to learn something.

Better use doctrine2 or an equivalent framework for your projects.